# Cache not working

Tags: php, mysql, caching, doctrine

I have the following function, but it is not caching. Is there something I'm missing? Environment: Doctrine Common and DBAL, PHP, MySQL. Should I not have the Cache ID a variable?

```
function getGeo($latitude, $longitude, $radius, $numResults, $volunteerPid, $startPosition, $pageSize)
    {
        $cacheDriver = new Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();
        $geoQuery = $cacheDriver->fetch($volunteerPid);
        if ($geoQuery === false) {
            $geoQuery = $this->connection->prepare("call sproc_qryGeo($latitude, $longitude, $radius, $numResults, $volunteerPid, $startPosition, $pageSize)");
            $cacheDriver->save($volunteerPid, $geoQuery);
            echo "NOT CACHED";
        }
        return $geoQuery;
    }
```

Comment: afaik `ArrayCache` is like a flash message, it's stored on a page only. After page reloading it's gone. Is it your situation? Do you expect caching with page reloading?

Comment: Ok. I've tried to use Result Cache now, but it's erroring out on `$config->setResultCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache());` even though the ApcCache.php file is in the Doctrine\Common\Cache folder. I get the error `Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration::setResultCacheImpl() must be an instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Cache\Cache, instance of Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache ` Any idea why I would get that error?

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comes from [cache types definintions on Doctrine site](http://doctrine-common.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html#introduction) `ArrayCache` has a lifetime of a request. So, after you reload the page - your cache is **gone**.

So, if this is your case - think of another cache storage, Doctrine supports a bunch of them.